# Resample data monthly in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, zoo

I have a large csv file example below,

```
> data <- fread('data.csv', sep = ",")
> data
              name year value       
    1: Afghanistan 1800   11
    2:     Albania 1800   22
    3:     Algeria 1800   6
    4: Afghanistan 1801   48
    5:     Albania 1801   60
    6:     Algeria 1801   120 

   ---                                  
46509: Afghanistan 2040   108
46510:     Albania 2040   72
46511:     Algeria 2040   36
```

my goal is to resample this data to monthly and interpolate value column as shown below, (Afghanistan 1800)

```
              name      year    value       
    1: Afghanistan     Jan 1800   1
    1: Afghanistan     Feb 1800   2
    1: Afghanistan     Mar 1800   3
    1: Afghanistan     May 1800   4
    1: Afghanistan     Jun 1800   5
    1: Afghanistan     Jul 1800   6
    1: Afghanistan     Aug 1800   7
    1: Afghanistan     Sep 1800   8
    1: Afghanistan     Oct 1800   9
    1: Afghanistan     Nov 1800   10
    1: Afghanistan     Dec 1800   11
    2:     Albania     Jan 1800   2



   ---                                  
46509: Afghanistan         2040   108
46510:     Albania         2040   72
46511:     Algeria         2040   36
```

I have tried several options without success, the closest have gotten as shown below,

```
> data <- as.zoo(data)
> m <- na.approx(data(time(data), 0:11/12, "+"))
Error in approx(x[!na], y[!na], xout, ...) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In data(time(data), 0:11/12, "+") : data set ‘time(data)’ not found
2: In data(time(data), 0:11/12, "+") : data set ‘0:11/12’ not found
3: In data(time(data), 0:11/12, "+") : data set ‘+’ not found
4: In xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : NAs introduced by coercion
> head(m)
           Afghanistan Albania  Algeria 
1800-01-31      11     24          6
1800-02-28      11     24          6
1800-03-31      11     24          6 
1800-04-30      11     24          6
1800-05-31      11     24          6
1800-06-30      11     24          6
```

Thoughts on how to achieve my desired results?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by re-sampling? Your values are not already part of your data so you can re-sample them. Looks like you're adding more rows to the ones you already have. 2. How does the monthly process work? Why is April missing from Afghanistan? 3. How is the value column generated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're looking for, let me know if this is closer to what you had in mind.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"),
  year = c(1800, 1800, 1800, 1801, 1801, 1801),
  value = c(11, 22, 6, 48, 60, 120),
  month = 1
)

cols <- c("month", "value")

res <- setDT(df)[, .SD[match(1:12, month)], by = .(name, year)]
res[, month := seq(.N), by = .(name, year)]
res[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, na.approx, na.rm = FALSE), .SDcols = cols, by = name]
```

**Output**

```
           name year     value month
 1: Afghanistan 1800  11.00000     1
 2: Afghanistan 1800  14.08333     2
 3: Afghanistan 1800  17.16667     3
 4: Afghanistan 1800  20.25000     4
 5: Afghanistan 1800  23.33333     5
 6: Afghanistan 1800  26.41667     6
 7: Afghanistan 1800  29.50000     7
 8: Afghanistan 1800  32.58333     8
 9: Afghanistan 1800  35.66667     9
10: Afghanistan 1800  38.75000    10
11: Afghanistan 1800  41.83333    11
12: Afghanistan 1800  44.91667    12
13:     Albania 1800  22.00000     1
14:     Albania 1800  25.16667     2
15:     Albania 1800  28.33333     3
16:     Albania 1800  31.50000     4
17:     Albania 1800  34.66667     5
18:     Albania 1800  37.83333     6
19:     Albania 1800  41.00000     7
20:     Albania 1800  44.16667     8
21:     Albania 1800  47.33333     9
22:     Albania 1800  50.50000    10
23:     Albania 1800  53.66667    11
24:     Albania 1800  56.83333    12
25:     Algeria 1800   6.00000     1
26:     Algeria 1800  15.50000     2
27:     Algeria 1800  25.00000     3
28:     Algeria 1800  34.50000     4
29:     Algeria 1800  44.00000     5
30:     Algeria 1800  53.50000     6
31:     Algeria 1800  63.00000     7
32:     Algeria 1800  72.50000     8
33:     Algeria 1800  82.00000     9
34:     Algeria 1800  91.50000    10
35:     Algeria 1800 101.00000    11
36:     Algeria 1800 110.50000    12
37: Afghanistan 1801  48.00000     1
...
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"),
  year = c(1800, 1800, 1800, 1801, 1801, 1801),
  value = c(11, 22, 6, 48, 60, 120),
  month = 1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do the following:

```
 library(tidyverse)

 data %>%
    arrange(name, value) %>%
    select(name, year, value)
```